# How to access contentDocument of embed element in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-html

I load an SVG within an HTML file with the embed element. But now I want to change the color of an gradient within this SVG. In JavaScript there is the contentDocument which I can access to query for the gradient that I am looking for. 
It appears that the contentDocument is absent fro the embedElement, so how do I do that in Dart?

Here is an example how it can be done in JavaScript: [Accessing SVG content in JS](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html)

The SVG is embedded like this:

```
<embed class="emb" src="images/svglogo.svg" width="100" height="100" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

Karsten

Comment: Can you paste in the JavaScript code that works?

Comment: Also, please paste in some HTML code that contains a simple SVG.

Comment: I updated the question for clarification of what I want to do.

Comment: It sounds like you should open a feature request at http://dartbug.com/new. Glad you found a work-around.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Opened bug https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12751

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a work-around that avoids the problem. You can simply load the SVG file with a HttpRequest like this:

```dart
HttpRequest.getString("../imgs/redLed.svg").then((r)=>svgLED=r);
```

then insert the String as SvgElement into the DOM like this:

```dart
SvgElement svg=new SvgElement.svg(svgLED);
bla.nodes.add(svg);
```

You can then query the SVG like a normal HTML Element:

```dart
svg.query("#lowVal").attributes["stop-color"]=lowOn;
```